# Maven connection reset in AWS instance

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, connection-reset

My Maven build is running in AWS instance and it was able to download the required dependencies but at the end it is failing because of the below issue. Can anyone please suggest what is going wrong?

**Note:** We are not using `Settings.xml` file

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) on
>   project someproject: Execution default-jar of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar failed: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4 ->
>   org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5: Could not
>   transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset ->
>   [Help 1]

Full Stack Track Trace:

```
> > org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal
> > org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) on project someproject: Execution default-jar of goal
> > org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar failed: Plugin >  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at
> > org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5    at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution
> default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar
> failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of
> its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies
> at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4 ->
> org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>   ... 20 more Caused by:
> org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4 ->
> org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:214)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:400)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:372)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
>   ... 21 more Caused by:
> org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to
> collect dependencies at
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4 ->
> org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:202)
>   ... 26 more Caused by:
> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to
> read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5
>   at
> org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
>   ... 28 more Caused by:
> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
> transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from/to
> central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset  at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
>   ... 35 more Caused by:
> org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not
> transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.5 from/to
> central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset  at
> org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
>   ... 38 more Caused by:
> org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connection reset  at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
>   at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
>   at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)  at
> org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
>   at
> org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
>   ... 43 more Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset   at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)   at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)   at
> sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)  at
> sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)   at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)     at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
>   at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)    at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:832)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:983)
>   ... 52 more
```

Comment: Can someone please help here.

Comment: I have added full stacktrace of the issue. Can someone point out the issue please.

Comment: can someone throw some light on this

Comment: It's been a long time. can someone suggest what is going wrong here.